# Show month in google chart hAxis

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

We are trying to show horizontal and vertical lines in google chart. For this we need to use hAxis and vAxis attribute.

But hAxis.format does not have any format for month, So how we can show vertical line?

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', ],
    ['Jan', 1000],
    ['Feb', 1170],
    ['Mar', 660],
    ['Apr', 1030]
]);

var options = {
    title: '',
    hAxis: {
        title: 'Year',
        minValue: 0,
        titleTextStyle: {
            color: '#333'
        },
        gridlines: {
            color: '#f3f3f3',
            count: 5
        },
         format: 'MMM'
    },
    vAxis: {
        minValue: 0,
        gridlines: {
            color: '#f3f3f3',
            count: 5
        }
    }
};
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j29Pt/408/)

And here is year jsFiddle which is showing both lines( horizontal and vertical )

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/j29Pt/3/)

Comment: Can you explain bit more what you realy want to show in Y axis

Comment: I want to show month in x-axis of chart, With chart cells as you can see in http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/j29Pt/3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is, but it is not so straight forward.
First thing you should know is that there is **no** option to create vertical lines for a major column of type `string`. So we need to use a column type of `number` for example and fix the labels later.

To do that we define the datatable like this:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number', 'Month');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        data.addRows([
        [{v: 0, f:'Jan'}, 1000],
        [{v: 1, f:'Feb'}, 1170],
        [{v: 2, f:'Mar'}, 660],
        [{v: 3, f:'Apr'}, 1030]
    ]);
```

Where we set number values but also string labels for the `Month` axis.
With just this and the `format` attribute removed, we would get vertical lines but numbers instead of the strings for the x axis labels, which is not what we want.
To fix this we can set `hAxis` `ticks` to force the correct labels in the plot.

```
var options = {
        title: '',
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Month',
            titleTextStyle: {
                color: '#333'
            },
            baseline: 0,
            gridlines: {
                color: '#f3f3f3',
              count: 4
            },
           ticks: [{v: 0, f:'Jan'},{v: 1, f:'Feb'},{v: 2, f:'Mar'},{v: 3, f:'Apr'}], // <------- This does the trick
        },
        vAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            gridlines: {
                color: '#f3f3f3',
                count: 5
            }
        }
    };
```

Hereby the complete working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j29Pt/417/

Comment: Can you please  check this  question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34674928/fill-one-color-in-google-chart

Comment: I did :) glad the answer helped.